# Popup Defocussing without a popup showing - Kivy - Python

Tags: python, kivy, popup, kivy-language

In the process of building an application in Kivy, I stumbled across this behaviour of my popup when the label text was too large for the size of the popup.

[image]

I have decided that i prefer the look of the error message showing in this way and I was wondering if there was a way to get this to happen but without the popup box showing underneath the error message?

I tried setting the size_hint vales to zero but that just landed me with this

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this defocussing of the main window without a popup box showing?

Thanks!

EDIT

I have now included a minimal working example, apologies for having not done so previously.

As a reminder, i'm looking for a way to get the error message to appear as an overlay to the whole app window, but without the popup window showing too.

Thanks!

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup


class Example(App):

    def build(self):
        return ExampleWindow()


class ExampleWindow(Button):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.popup = MessageBox()


class MessageBox(Popup):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Example().run()
```

Example.kv

```
<ExampleWindow>:
    text: "Open Message"
    on_release: root.popup.open()

<MessageBox>:
    size_hint: 0.3, 0.3
    Label:
        font_size: 36
        text: "MESSAGE TEXT IS HERE!"
```

Comment: show some runnable code

Comment: Hi, I have provided some sample code above, apologies for having not done that originally!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not customize the `Popup` widget but yiu can create your own custom one by using the prenet widget of the `Popup` one which is `ModalView` like follwing

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.modalview import ModalView

kv = Builder.load_string('''
Screen:
    Button:
        text:'press to see text'
        on_press:app.add_floating_label()


''')


class MyApp(App):
    view = None

    def build(self):
        return kv

    def open_floating_label(self):
        self.view = ModalView(auto_dismiss=True, size_hint=(None, None), background_color=[.1, .1, .1, 0],
                              size=(300, 75))
        self.view.add_widget(Label(text="MESSAGE TEXT IS HERE!"))
        self.view.open()
    # you can also close the view using dismiss method
    def close_floating_label(self):
        self.view.close()


MyApp().run()
```

Comment: perfect, thats exactly what i'm after!